# Fastest algorithm for all whole lat/lng intersections in a rotated ellipse?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, starling-framework, cartesian-coordinates

I'm working on a tile engine for a 2.5D game with parallel (but rotatable) projection. Tiles are flat quads having their vertices adjusted and placements set based on camera position and x/y rotation. There is no yaw (z). Writing the engine in Starling.

The camera's visible area can be described as the grid area that falls within an arbitrarily rotated and arbitrarily tall ellipse of a fixed width.

What I'd like to do now is get a list of the tiles which fall within the screen space, prior to having to project them and without having to test each coordinate set against the zoom radius / sin / cos. This can be a dirty set as long as it's larger than the radius. But I'm looking for the least dirty and most optimized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, this is similar to a filling problem.

You overlay a rectangular grid over the ellipse, and you want to list the tiles that have at least a corner inside the ellipse. With appropriate scaling, this is the same as scanfilling the ellipse.

Put the ellipse in its implicit form, `ax² + 2bxy + cy² + 2dx + 2ey + f = 0`, with coordinates scaled/translated so that the grid points fall at integer coordinates. You first determine the useful range of `y` values. Then for every scanline, you determine the extreme values of `x`.

Let `y` be fixed, you have a second degree equation in `x`: `ax² + 2(by + d)x + (cy² + 2ey + f) = 0`.

Its discriminant is `(by+d)- a(cy²+2ey+f) = (b²-ac)y² + 2(bd-ae)y + (d²-af)`.

Solving this second degree equation in `y` gives you the range of `y` values; take the ceiling of the smallest and the floor of the largest.

Then for every integer in this range, solve for `x` and you'll get the horizontal range.

[Note that I am using discriminant B²-AC for an equation in the form At² + 2Bt + C= 0.]

Comment: Beware that the exact use of floor/ceiling to get the indexes need to be scrutinized, to make sure to properly handle limit cases with a tile hitting the ellipse by a side but not by a corner.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer and will mark it so, although I haven't tested it. I did try a scanline approach based on a rectangle, but had fluttering/missing tiles at the ceiling/floor intersections working their way l/r up/down -- I think every time a rotation was evenly divisibly by 30º. Would have had to use some float math to fill those so I switched methods and made the largest possible rectangle from the high/low coordinates, then test each within that to see if it screens. It's not too slow. But I'll give this a try when I get to optimize it more. Thanks for such a detailed post!

Comment: Do these artifacts arise when two vertexes are on the same horizontal ? Can you show a sample picture that shows the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted that function when I gave up on that approach.  But yes that is exactly when it happened, when there were two vertices on the same horizontal. That explains the motion of the artifact clearly as well, during camera rotation. FWIW, what I was doing was starting at the upper left screen corner and incrementing whole numbers along the longer axis (lat or lng) to the upper right, while decrementing the shorter axis by a float (b(short)-a(short))/(a(long)-b(long)), then moving to the next row which would start at (d(long)-a(long))/(d(short)-a(short).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an octree or a k-d tree when the tiles doesn't move.

Comment: The way the tiles are accessed or sorted isn't important. Right now they're just in a flat vector and it's easy to access whichever ones I want by their lat/lng coordinates (which are integers).

Another way of asking the question is, for an arbitrary rectangle at any angle over a regular grid, how can you get ranges of the grid that intersect the rectangle *without* checking every single grid tile?

Comment: You can check the upper bounds for example if you traverse the grid zigzag it's the mostsignficant bits.

Comment: well, remember the camera can be rotated to any angle. So unless it's not rotated (or only rotated to a known angle), checking the upper and lower bounds might give me a list of tiles that are not in order from low-to-high latitude or longitude. One axis or the other could be reversed. I'm looking for something like a diamond pattern that would be used for an isometric view, except the variance would be anywhere between *1 /1 and *2 /2 tiles per row, I think...(??)

Answer (score 0):

I do this for mine (huge DTM) terrain grid rendering:

1. cast few rays along the border of mine screen (camera frustrum Z-near plane)

   - in direction of that pixel in camera
   - it is the same line as it would start from focus point and goes through the pixel
2. compute all intersections between rays and mine terrain grid on ellipsoid surface

   - keep min,max for each used grid line
   - this will give you the list of used cells
3. fill in the blank spaces

   - enlarge min max line/col by few grid cells just to be sure
   - if any line is missing (not hit by ray but neighbouring lines are) then interpolate it too
   - this will give list of all cells needed to render

It looks like this:

- global overview:
- [image: cam view]
- Znear plane detail (near surface camera position viewing down):
- [image: grid hit]
- I have 6 degrees of freedom so I need to cast rays along whole screen area not just border
- in your case 4 rays should be enough
- and the ellipse mask can be added later
- or cast more rays along your ellipse view circumference/perimeter

And this is how it looks after rendering (viewing towards horizont):

[image]

- Hipparcos stars up to +12 mag
- terrain DTM 50m cell grid size
- texture interpolated from NASA GeoCover Circa 1990/2000 SWIR 14.75m -> 50m DTM aligned